# How to increase concurrent parallel tasks with System.Threading.Parallel (.Net 4.0)

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm experimenting with the new System.Threading.Parallel methods like parallel for and foreach.

They seem to work nicely but I need a way to increase the number of concurrent threads that are executed which are 8 (I have a Quad core).

I know there is a way I just can find the place thy hidden the damn property.

Gilad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

quote:

```
var query = from item in source.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
        where Compute(item) > 42
        select item;
```

In cases where a query is performing a significant amount of non-compute-bound work such as File I/O, it might be beneficial to specify a degree of parallelism greater than the number of cores on the machine.

from: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425(VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

IF you are using `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach` you can specify a `ParallelOptions` object which has a property `MaxDegreesOfParallelism`. Unfortunately this is just a maximum limit as the name suggests, and does not provide a lower bound guarantee. For the relationsship to `WithDegreeOfParallelism` see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/29/9655514.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

*MAY NOT* - enough said. Blindy commented it correctly